# Does the "Structural Ergonomics" equipment increase power recharge beyond 200%?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

The description for the "Structural Ergonomics I" gear bonus equipment states that it increases power recharge speed by 5%. Will this increase your power recharge rate beyond the normal 200% max?

When I equip a heavy weapon I can see the impact on a power's recharge rate (in seconds) when I view that power's details. However, the bonuses given by gear aren't reflected in the power's details so I can't tell if it's increasing past the 200% max.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. Going over 200% however provides an extremely poor diminishing return, which is why the effect is barely noticeable.

Assuming that you are using Warp with 2 setups.

Warp level 6 with 200% recharge
8 / (1 + 2 + 0.25) = 2.46s

Warp level 6 with 205% recharge (structural ergonomics I)
8 / (1 + 2 + 0.25 + 0.05) = 2.42s

*Note that the 0.25 comes from warp's second level, increasing recharge by 25%.